# Prove weak convergence (proof verification)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

We are given a distribution, $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=\frac k n)=2^{-k}$ for $k= 1, 2, 3,\dots$. Check if this converges in distribution and if it does find the limit distribution.

I think it does, the CDF function for $Y_n$ looks as follows (?):

$$F_n=\begin{cases}
0 &nt<1
\\ \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor nt \rfloor} 2^{-k} &nt\geq1
\end{cases}$$

in the limit we get $$F_n\to\begin{cases}
0 & t\leq0
\\ 1 &t>0
\end{cases}$$

This is not a distribution because it is not right continous however
$$F(t)=\begin{cases}
0 & t<0
\\ 1 &t\geq0
\end{cases}$$

is a distribution and $F_n$ converges to $F$ in points of continuity of $F$ right?

So indeed $F_n$ converges.

Comment: in the first $\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor t \rfloor} 2^{-k}$ you should replace $t$ by $nt$. The rest is wrong because of this mistake.

Comment: @justt what about now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you took a limit improperly.  Try this hint instead:

Hint: Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and calculate $\mathbb{P}(Y_n > \epsilon)$.  What happens as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I typed it wrong! I did not even considered your hint, but I think it is alright now.

Comment: No in fact it was really wrong, however now after another editing it is right i think.